# Convergence of a sequence of integrals defined recursively

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Let $g:[0,\frac1{2}]\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous function. Let us define the sequence $g_n(t)$ as $g_1(t)=g$ and $$g_{n+1}(t)=\int_0^tg_n(s)ds$$ for $n\ge1$. Is it true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n!g_n(t)=0\forall t\in[0,\frac1{2}]$

I think yes, and may be we have to use the Cauchy formula for repeated integrals. Is there any other way to prove this? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888375/uniformly-convergence-of-f-n1x-intx-0-f-ntdt or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109559/f-nx-is-defined-by-f-n1x-int-0xf-ntdt-prove-sum-1-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Note that $g_{n+1}(t)\le t\max g_n\le\frac12\max g_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply Taylor to $g_{n+1}(t)$ and note that $|g(t)|\leq C$ on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, since $g$ is continuous:

$$g_{n+1}(t) = \underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k!}g_{n+1}^{(k)}(0)}_{=0}t^k + \underbrace{g_{n+1}^{(n)}}_{=g}(\tau_n)\frac{t^{n}}{n!} $$ $$\Rightarrow n!\cdot|g_{n+1}(t)|\leq C\frac{1}{2^n}$$